# JBOSS Monitoring tool on UNIX

Tags: unix, jboss, monitoring

I have a web application deployed on a jboss server running on a unix machine.
I want to be able to monitor threads, CPU times ,requests, etc. , for gauging application performance on the server.
What might be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The jboss.system:type=ServerInfo](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossas/freezone/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Additional_Services-Memory_and_Thread_Monitoring.html) MBean provides several attributes that can be used to monitor the thread and memory usage in a JBoss instance.

A few open source tools for remote monitoring and administration using Java Management Extensions (JMX)

- [Jmanage](http://www.jmanage.org/)
- [mx4j](http://mx4j.sourceforge.net/)
- [mc4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mc4j/)

Answer (score 1):

There is also [RHQ](http://www.jboss.org/rhq) that offers a lot more than just monitoring like alerting on (changed) values, can run operations on the servers (restart etc), can make config changes and also deploy applications on the server (or whole servers on a machine).

Answer (score 0):

Solaris/Linux/*BSD? On Solaris and *BSD, you can consider using [DTrace](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/dtrace/index.jsp) as a general application monitoring tool.